# Cech Cohomology Hartshorne III 4.4

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

I´m stuck with the section $c)$ of the following Hartshorne´s exercise[image]

I have just proved $a)$ and $b)$. I wonder if you can help me. Thank you for your time